# Mysql subquery COUNT in same Table returns NULL

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

I have this MySQL table and I want to update multiple columns ( children, size) using COUNT() and SUM() on same table.

mytable

```
id  parentid  name      userid   path    children   privatesize    size
=======================================================================
1   0         Test-1    1        NULL      5        20             125
2   0         Test-2    1        NULL      0        15             15
3   1         Test-3    1        /1/       3        25             75
4   1         Test-4    1        /1/       0        30             30
5   3         Test-5    1        /1/3/     0        10             10
6   3         Test-6    1        /1/3/     1        30             40
7   6         Test-7    1        /1/3/6/   0        10             10
8   0         Test-8    2        NULL      0        20             20
```

*Notes:*

*size = privatesize + children privatesize*

*NULL = "", just for demonstration*

Let's update for now just one column, `children` column.
Right now I use MySQL stored functions to calculate children:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `getchildren`( rowid INT, uid INT ) RETURNS INT(11)

BEGIN

DECLARE children    INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT( `mytable`.`id` ) INTO children
FROM `dbname`.`mytable`
WHERE `mytable`.`path` LIKE CONCAT( '%/',rowid ,'/%' ) AND `mytable`.`userid` = uid;

RETURN  children;
END
```

Test function getchildren:

```
SELECT dbname.getchildren( 1, 1 );
```

This returns number 5

To update rows ( Example id 2 and 5 ) I use this query:

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`mytable`
SET `children` = getchildren( `mytable`.`id` , `mytable`.`userid` )
WHERE `mytable`.`id` IN ( 2, 5 )
```

**And works correctly.**

But I don't want to use functions because later I need to update multiple columns (example: size ) and I don't want to call functions for every columns.

For that I have tried this query:

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`mytable` mt
INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT `mytable`.`path` AS path, COUNT( `mytable`.`id`)  AS countid
        FROM `dbname`.`mytable`
        GROUP BY `mytable`.`userid`
        ) sub ON  `sub`.`path` LIKE CONCAT( "%/", `mt`.`id` , "/%" )
SET `mt`.`children` = `sub`.`countid`
WHERE `mt`.`id` IN ( 2, 5 );
```

In fact without success, this change the value of children to NULL.

Even the same method (using the same subquery logic) doesn't work in SELECT, returns NULL or returns multiple rows (with correct count for each group) if I change GROUP BY: `id` or to `path`.
It looks like COUNT() doesn't work like usual on subquery.

What I'm missing in this query? Can someone explain what really cause this behavior or I'm wrong at all?

[Online SELECT Test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b29a/3)

Thanks.

Comment: Your subquery should be grouping on `path`, not `userid`.  Execute the subquery on its own. You should see the correct result, and it _is_ permissible to use the `COUNT(*)` aggregate in a `FROM` clause subquery.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This doesn't works correctly. By Grouping by path subquery returns multiple rows, so in this case doesn't count all children. Tested before and now just to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: I want to upload a test online but sqlfiddle is down.

Comment: I think you have right but I'm not able to figure out how to count returned rows from subquery. lol 5:30 am here. I will try later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many times I'm stuck with a simple "trick" and I will post here. I'm not happy with my solution but at last it works. I'm using [User Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) as a way to "return" from [User Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html) multiple variables (INT Variables).

getchildren( rowid, userid) function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `getchildren`( rowid INT, uid INT ) RETURNS INT(11)

BEGIN

DECLARE children    INT DEFAULT 0;
SET @childrensize := 0;


SELECT 
    COUNT( `mytable`.`id` ),
    SUM( `mytable`.`privatesize` )
INTO children, @childrensize

FROM `dbname`.`mytable`
WHERE 
    `mytable`.`path` LIKE CONCAT( '%/',rowid ,'/%' )
    AND `mytable`.`userid` = uid;

RETURN  children;
END
```

Test New Function:

```
SELECT `dbname`.getchildren( 1, 1 ) AS children, @childrensize AS size;
```

This returns:

```
Children   size
===============
5          105
```

Now let's update rows with id 2 and 5 (both children and size)

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`mytable`
SET 
    `children` = getchildren( `mytable`.`id`, `mytable`.`userid` ),
    `size` = `privatesize` + IFNULL( @childrensize, 0 )
WHERE `mytable`.`id` IN ( 2, 5 )
```

**And works correctly!**

The logic is simple, each time the function getchildren is called he updates user defined variable **@childrensize**. If the row has no children the function set @childrensize to NULL, for that IFNULL( @childrensize, 0 ) is necessary.

In this way, the function will called one time for each row and update multiple columns.

**UPDATES:**

Here is the right solution for this case:

```
UPDATE `dbname`.`mytable` mt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  `mtc1`.`id`, count(*) numchildren, sum( `mtc2`.`privatesize` ) AS tsize
    FROM `tsdata`.`mytable` mtc1, `tsdata`.`mytable` mtc2 
    WHERE `mtc2`.`path` LIKE CONCAT( '%/',mtc1.id,'/%' )
    GROUP by `mtc1`.id)
mtc ON `mtc`.`id` = `mt`.`id`

SET
    `mt`.`children`= IFNULL( `mtc`.numchildren, 0 ),
    `mt`.`size` = `mt`.`privatesize` + IFNULL( `mtc`.tsize, 0 )
WHERE `mt`.`id`  in ( 2, 5 );
```

The performance is almost 40% higher than using function (On the method above)